# Extract data from a list within dictionary using JSON

Tags: json, data-extraction

I am working with an OKR program where I am trying to extract the Objectives and Key Results from its API (sample anonymized JSON output below). I want to use a while loop to iterate through the one or many key results an objective may have. However, I get a traceback error with **[keymetric_start]** in the line "metric_name =(u['people_goals'][0]['goal_metrics'][keymetric_start]['metric_name'])" saying "IndexErrorL list index out of range".  How do I get it to accept the keymetric_start as a variable? Thanks so much!

```js
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "",
  "data": {
    "totalCount": 14,
    "goal": [{
        "user_id": 12345,
        "people_goals": [{
            "goal_id": 13579,
            "goal_name": "move the business forward",
            "goal_metrics": [{
                "metric_id": "2468",
                "metric_name": "Raise more money",
                "metric_progress": "50"
              },
              {
                "metric_id": "2469",
                "metric_name": "Get more financing",
                "metric_progress": "25"
              },
              {
                "metric_id": "2470",
                "metric_name": "Understand risks",
                "metric_progress": "75"
              }
            ],
            "goal_metrics_count": 3
          },
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
}
```

```html
for u in js['data']['goal']:
  goal_name = (u['people_goals'][0]['goal_name'])
  keymetric_count = (u['people_goals'][0]['goal_metrics_count'])
  keymetric_start = 0
  while keymetric_start <= keymetric_count:
    metric_name =(u['people_goals'][0]['goal_metrics'][keymetric_start]['metric_name'])
    keymetric_start = keymetric_start +1
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel the issue is this line - `while keymetric_start <= keymetric_count:`

you are saying they both can be equal which means `keymetric_start` could have a maximum value of 3.

However, there are only 3 elements inside `goal_metrics` so the highest allowed value for `keymetric_start` should be 2 (not 3) due to zero based indexing of arrays.

You can try doing this in your while clause:

```js
while keymetric_start < keymetric_count:
```